# Allow laravel relationship, only if condition is met

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**I edited the question, since my first try was completly misleading. Sorry for that.**

I am building an api with laravel and have the following models/tables:

```
user
---
id
name

customers
---
id
name
user_id

projects
---
id
name
user_id
customer_id (can be NULL)
```

A project always belongs to a user and optionally can also belongs to a customer. A customer always belongs to an user. For example:

```
users = [
    {id: 1, name: "user1"},
    {id: 2, name: "user2"}
]

customers = [
    {id: 1, name: "c1", user_id: 1},
    {id: 2, name: "c2", user_id: 1},
    {id: 3, name: "c3", user_id: 2}
]

projects = [
    {id: 1, name: "p1", user_id: 1},
    {id: 2, name: "p2", user_id: 1, customer_id: 1},
    {id: 3, name: "p3", user_id: 2, customer_id: 2}
]
```

How to prevent, that someone creates invalid data in the DB, by creating or updating a project, with a customer_id which does belong to a customer of another user then the user_id of the project. For example:

newProject = {id: 4, name: "p4", user_id: 1, customer_id: 3}

As you can see, the new project should belong to the user 1 and the customer 3, which is not possible.

Comment: Put in the controller a check like this: `Auth::id() == $customer->user_id`

Comment: Thats exactly what I am doing right now, but I am looking for a better, more flexible way to do this, because I would have to implement it in all places, where the user can modify the customer (for example nested relationsships)

Comment: You need an authrization system: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization

Comment: Thats a really general answer. Of course I need an authorization system.

Comment: Sorry but generic question => generic answer. You can start to write some code, and, if you have some specific problem you can ask here

Comment: Check for laravel [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies). It will help you to go on granular level with permissions

Comment: Ok, I saw now, that my question was to simplyfied and misleading. I now updated it

Answer (score 1):

Most elegant solution would be to use a Laravel request validation system, because that was your problem is actually : a complex validation constraint on an incoming request.

To do that :

- Create a rule, there is a generator for that. Inside define your specific rule logic. Here is the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules
- Create a Form request. there is a generator for that too, and apply your rule in it. Hre is the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation
- Inject that request in your controller action. If the validation fails, the code in your controller won't even be executed and framework will return an HTTP error code 422.

That's the Laravel way to do it.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading question. My problem isn't an authorization problem. Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Ok Sorry for that bad answer. Your issue is a validation constraint, because you want to create a project only if the data received by the API + user_id matches a certain constraint. I would recommend you to check custom validation rules and Form (beside the name, it works with API) Request validation rules ,

Comment: No it was my fault, since the question was misleading at first place. I think you are right and validation is the way to got.

Comment: Ok i will edit my answer in case someone else comes to the page, it's not clear where is the correct answer at the moment....

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this way.

```
 class User extends Eloquent {

        public function scopePopular($query)
        {
            return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
        }

    }
```

You can call another method from your model if its true then you can send it to controller.

For More [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

Hope it will be helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: dont put authorization logic inside the Model, use the controller for that.

In the Model you can define scopes you can use to restrict access to authorized list of models.

You really have to read the authorization chapter in the [laravel official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization).

Update: in the controller you can validate that the customer the user input is one of the user customers, you can even use a Form request Validation, in case returns an error. For Validation you can [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation).

Comment: Sorry for my misleading question. My problem isn't an authorization problem. Please have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to register a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies). Follow the instructions on the documentation page linked to do that, then in your policy method include this:

```
public function update(User $user, Customer $customer)
{
    return $customer->user_id === $user->id;
}
```

and

```
public function create(User $user, Customer $customer)
{
    return $customer->user_id === $user->id;
}
```

This will make it work on the `create` and `update` methods.

> The important part to note here is:

```
return $customer->user_id === $user->id;
```

This will ensure that, for a given `customer` and `user`, the `user_id` on the customer matches the `id` on the `user`, which is what you want.

To make it work on the Projects model you will need to do this in the auth service provider:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

protected $policies = [
    Project::class => ProjectPolicy::class,
];
```

Where `ProjectPolicy` is the name of policy that you set when you do `php artisan make:policy` (as explained in the linked docs).